# How to make JavaScript link to another page

Tags: javascript, html, function, authentication, hyperlink

I would like to know how to make a JavaScript function link to another site.

Here is my code so far.

```
var user = "iamauser1"
var pass = "iamauser2"
var userfield = document.getElementByName("UserEntry")
var passfield = document.getElementByName("PassEntry")
var submitbtn = document.getElementByName("SubmitButton")

function checkLogin() {
    if userfield == user && passfield == pass {

    }
}
```

What I am aiming to do, just to test this, is to make the above function link to a page that says, 'Login Successful!'. Can anyone help me?

So, I want to make a redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
window.location.href = 'YOUR URL';
```

Then the browser will navigate to the URL specified.

Comment: Have a look at your browser console and check if there are any errors displayed. By your example above your `if` statement is wrong, it should be `if (userfield == user && passfield == pass) {` on the top line.

Comment: How do I access that on Chrome? I know how on Firefox, but not Chrome.

Comment: F12 on Windows or cmd + option + I on OS X. The console's at the bottom of the Developer Tools window.